# Net Core: Difference between Private Members and Data Annotations for Data Checking

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-annotations

What is the difference between having private members and Data annotations for data validation checking in classes? Does one way often a benefit over the other, or they just the same. I don't have an opinion, just curious.

1)

For example here, I Need Private member for (less than/greater than checking).

```
public class PageModel
{
    private int page;
    public int Page
    {
        get => page;
        set
        {
            if (value < 1 || value > 100) { throw new ArgumentException("Number should be between 1 and 100"); }
            else page = value;
        }
    }
```

2)

```
public class PageModel
{
    [Range(1,100, ErrorMessage="Number should be between 1 and 100")] 
    public int Page{get;set;}
}
```

Are data annotations just as safe as private members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is a huge difference.

If you raise an exception in the setter, there is no way to set the value without triggering the validation.

if you use a Data Annotation, you only add metadata to an property on how to validate it. But you need something to use this metadata to do the validation. EFCore or asp.net use this information to do some validation.

That means, that the following code throws an argument exception, if you use your first implementation, but executes, if you use a Data Annotation.

```
new PageModel { Page = 300 };
```

To manually execute the validation of the Data Annotations, you have to call [Validator.TryValidateObject](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx).